# How to find if if a particular column has zero value in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

Trust you all are doing well!

I have this dataframe that contains 0 and float numbers in column ('BP_MOVE') , there could be two conditions

1. Zero in any row of column ('BP_MOVE')
2. Zero in each row of column ('BP_MOVE')

[image]

Below is what i have tried, the first python statement covers the second case very well where each row has 0 value but it fails to cover the first case. similarly, the second python statement gives the following error, is there a way to hit two targets with one arrow ?

*The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().*

```
if (df['bp_move'] == 0).all():
if (df == 0).any(axis=1):
```

Comment: if df[df['bp_move'] == 0].any():

    myTeamsMessage.text('Hi Team, rates are showing staleness for today, please check' + df.to_html())

    myTeamsMessage.send()

Comment: You can try `df['a'].eq(0).any()`.

Comment: it still showing the same error

Comment: Sorry, but I don't not what `myTeamsMessage.send()` is. In you question you are talking about `pandas` and I thought `df` is a PandasDataFrame.

Comment: if (df['bp_move'] == 0).any(): this worked, thanks @mosc9575

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comment fros mosc9576 said, you can apply the same syntax you had int the `.all()`

```
if (df['bp_move'] == 0).all():
    print('all')
if (df['bp_move'] == 0).any():
    print('any')
```